# deleting textfile line in listview but is not saving c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a **ListView** that loads a .txt file with some phone numbers and when i click the delete button it  will delete the selected line from the **ListView**. When I click the button to delete, the button delete the line but doesn't save the file with the updated list.I'll provide more information if asked.

Thank you!!

**here is the delete button**

```
 public void Deletar_lista()
        {
            var caminho = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            caminho += "\\telefones.txt";

            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[0]);

        }
```

Comment: Thats because you're just removing it from the listview. The file remains unchanged. You'll need to write code to find the entry in the file and remove that too.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a little bit of code to go on here, but it appears that you are only deleting the item from the ListView.
Your application will not automatically know that you want it to save the updated content of the ListView to the file.

To do this, try the following:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(caminho);

using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(caminho))
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (!line.Contains(listView1.SelectedIndices[0].ToString()))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

This reads all the lines from the file, and if the selected line equals your deleted entry, it will not write it to the file.

Comment: To add, place this code above your `listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[0]);` line, as your program might not recognize the line if it is already deleted from the ListView.

Comment: I wrote the code you shared. Its deleting all the lines from the file now.

Comment: Can you supply me with an example of what is in your file and what is shown in the listview?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work. Here is what I done:

```
int ll_count = -1;    
            var caminho = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            caminho += "\\telefones.txt";
            if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja mesmo deletar o numero?", "Usuario", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(caminho);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(caminho))
                {

                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        ll_count++;

                        if (ll_count != listView1.SelectedIndices[0])
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }

                listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[0]);
```